# jquery.validate not working correctly with jquery-1.4.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The following script will display an error message upon unfocus.  I change it to jQuery 4.3 or newer, and it doesn't do so.  I know I am doing something stupid, but can't find it.  Please provide advise. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery validation</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script> 
        <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var validate = $("#signupForm").validate({
                    rules: {phone:'phoneUS'},
                    messages: {phone:'Enter a valid phone number'},
                    submitHandler: function(form) {alert('submit');}
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
            <label for="phone">phone</label>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery Validate are you using? Recent versions of jQV usually require recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0.  What's crazy is I have done this before and know it works.

Comment: When you change the version of jQuery, does it get loaded? May seem like a silly question, but more than once I've seen someone claim that a jQuery update broke their site, just to find that jQuery wasn't getting loaded.

Comment: Got loaded.  No silly questions 'cause I know when I figure this out, I will say "dang, that was silly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `phoneUS` method is defined in `additional-methods.js`. If you include this file (and make sure your input has a `type='text'`), it should work fine:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        phone: 'phoneUS'
    },
    messages: {
        phone: 'Enter a valid phone number'
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('submit');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
    <label for="phone">phone</label>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kzDnx/5/